# Weighted interval scheduling with variable weights

Tags: algorithm, scheduling, intervals

In the traditional weighted interval scheduling problem, we have a list `{i_1, ..., i_n}` of intervals with weights `w_j`. An algorithm to solve the weighted interval scheduling problem is given [here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~shuchi/courses/787-F09/scribe-notes/lec3.pdf) and is a basic dynamic programming problem. However, what happens when if in a schedule, the weight of a selected interval depends on the weight of the interval before it (and in turn, so that the weight depends on the order)? An example would be `w_j' = w_j'*(w_(j-1)' + 1)` where primed variables are the intrinsic weights and unprimed weights are the "actual" weights taking the order into account, i.e. the ones you actually use for the objective function. Is this problem NP-hard? It sure sounds like it.

Edit: To make this easier (also realistic) let's assume discrete, unit time.

Comment: Looking closer at the problem, I'm wondering why we can't just use DP so that the subproblems are "what can we accomplish up to time t and ending with job j" and not just "what can we accomplish up to time t"

Comment: @DennisMeng So, what you are suggesting is iterating over the start/end times, as in, look at all jobs with end time `t` then try to fit them in the schedule, using previous computations to inform the rest of the chain, then go to `t+1`?

Comment: If by "using previous computations to inform the rest of the chain", you mean "using previous computations to figure out the best I can do from the beginning to time `t`", then I think you've got the right idea. The main difference between what I was suggesting and what was done in the original problem is that when we look at previous computations, we don't just care about what time we've computed up to, but also what the last job used was in that computation.

Comment: @DennisMeng OK, thanks. One last thing: If I understand what you're talking about,  your suggestion is tacitly assuming that the functions involved for calculating weight are all increasing. For instance, if one of the functions is `f(x) = 1/(|x| + 1)` and we are meant to feed it the sum of the weights of the preceding intervals, then we'd like the sum of those weights to be as close to zero as possible. This would wreck the algorithm in general.

Comment: Hmm, I suppose that's true. Thanks for clearing that part up.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured it out. The algorithm is (please correct me if I'm wrong):

```
for t in times:
    if is_first(t):
        best_candidate = None
    else:
        best_candidate = best(t - 1)

    for interval in intervals if interval.end_time is t:
        value_i = f(best(interval.start_time) + interval)
        value_candidate = f(best_candidate)
        if value_i > value_candidate:
            best_candidate = best(interval.start_time) + interval

    best(t) = best_candidate

return best(times[-1])
```

where the collections `times, intervals` are the potential time stops of the intervals and the intervals themselves and `f` is the objective function.

The constant between iterations is: after the iteration over time `t` is finished, `best(t)` is the best schedule that ends with `t`. Note that because of the initialization step, `best(t) == best(t - 1)` is possible. Also note that as in my comment, this only works if `f` is monotone increasing, as `f` is meant to be applied to each individual interval based on the intervals before it. I use it in the manner here as shorthand.